# mvf field is not working with view dependant filter

Tags: chaos-tool-suite, views

mvf field is not working with view dependant filter.

I created a mvf field .

I want its view filter with view dependent filter module .

Its filter is working fine when the field is not in dependant list .
But when i inclued it with Dependent filter its not hiding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i have to change the field type .